# INSERT is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Ive been trying to do this insert but keep failing, this is a taxi company booking im using, mysql runs fine and i have echoed some strings to make sure its gets to this line, im not getting any errors but still no insert

```
 $insert_booking=("INSERT INTO booking(booking_id, user_id, booking_via, pickup_address, destination, latitude, longitude, booking_time, price, rate, mile_distance, car_type, passengers, luggage, approved, user_confirmed)  

  VALUES 

  ('$booking_id','$user_account_id','Website','".$_SESSION['pickup']."','".$_SESSION['destination']."','0','0','".$_SESSION['booking_time']."','".$_SESSION['price']."','".$_SESSION['rate']."','".$_SESSION['distance']."','".$_SESSION['car_type']."','".$_SESSION['passengers']."','".$_SESSION['luaggage']."','0','0')");
```

Comment: "luaggage" looks like a typo. How are you executing this? How are you checking that there is no error? **Why aren't you using prepared statements?**

Comment: $_SESSION['luaggage']

Comment: No one of your columns is numeric?

Comment: what is the error u r getting???

Comment: corrected luaggage and it seems to be fine, im not getting any error at all actually, it just doesnt do insert

Comment: I have some int columns but not numerical

Comment: didn't you miss function name, like `$insert_booking=$mysqli->query("INSERT ...`

Answer (score 0):

You havent used `mysql_query()` function or any other function to execute the query. Also i think you have added single quoted to variables that store `int` data, adding single quotes makes them a `string` datatype. For example, if `booking_id` is stored as `int` in the database remove the single quotes from `$booking_id`

The below code show how to insert `int` datatype and `string`/`varchar`/`text` etc datatype

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO booking(booking_id,pickup_address)
                       VALUES($booking_id,'".$_SESSION['pickup']."')") or die(my_error());
```

In my example `booking_id` is `int` and `pickup_address` is `varchar(100)`.